# Problem creating compound index in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Creating index via MongoShell

```
db.car.createIndex({brand:1 , model:1 , colour:1 ,fuelTypes:1},{unique:true})
```

Creating CompoundIndex via spring application

```
@Document
@CompoundIndex(def = "{ 'brand':1 , 'model':1 , 'colour':1 , 'fuelTypes':1 }",unique = true)
public class Car {

    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private List<FuelType> fuelTypes;
    private String colour;
}
```

I was able to create via Mongo shell but not thourgh spring application.What's wrong in the above code?Are n't they equivalent?
I checked After inserting atleast one document.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example I tried (creates a new collection, document and the compound index):

The `Car` POJO class:

```
@CompoundIndex(name = "car-cmp-idx", def = "{'brand': 1, 'model': 1}", unique = true)
@Document
public class Car {

    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private String colour;

    public Car() {

    }
    public Car(String brand, String model, String colour) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    // get/set methods. etc...
}
```

The application code to create a document in the (new) `car`: collection:

```
MongoOperations ops = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
Car car = new Car("Ford", "Model T", "Black");
ops.insert(car);
```

The result document verified from the `mongo` shell:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed46f4960c3f13e5edf43b6"),
        "brand" : "Ford",
        "model" : "Model T",
        "colour" : "Black",
        "_class" : "com.example.demo.Car"
}
```

The indexes:

```
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.car"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "brand" : 1,
                        "model" : 1
                },
                "name" : "car-cmp-idx",
                "ns" : "test.car"
        }
]
```